# Search content into two columns using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model like this one:

User:

```
string FirstName {get; set;}
string LastName {get; set; }
```

And I am doing a search where I want to search if the pattern that I send is part of the first name, part of the last name, or part of the whole thing concatened.

So I have basically have done this:

```
entities = entities.Where(user => user.Contains(text));
```

With an user extension method that does the following:

```
    public static bool Contains(this User user, string filter)
    {
        return user.FirstName.Contains(filter) ||
            user.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
            (user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName).Contains(filter);
    }
```

But I am always getting the following error:

(__filterText_1))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.'

I am assuming that is because of this part `(user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName)` but I'm currently not thinking of any other alternative.

Comment: What version of EF Core are you running?

Comment: @CameronTinker 2.2

Comment: Surely you can just add a property called FullName to User, aka public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName; then do a Contains on this property so EF doesn't handle the concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to not use an extension method and use

```
user.FirstName.Contains(filter) ||
            user.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
            (user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName).Contains(filter);
```

directly on the where instead of using it on an extension method

```
entities = entities.Where(user => user.FirstName.Contains(text) ||
                user.LastName.Contains(text) ||
                (user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName).Contains(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your extension method cannot be converted to SQL. Entity Framework uses expression trees in order to translate lambdas into SQL.

**OLD ANSWER**

Instead, your extension method can return an `Expression`, like this:

```c#
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> Contains(this User user, string filter)
{
    return user.FirstName.Contains(filter) ||
            user.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
            (user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName).Contains(filter);
}
```

Then you can use it in your `Where`.

**UPDATE ANSWER**

Instead of an extension method, you can create a private method in your class to build the filter expression, then pass that to your `Where`:

```c#
private Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetFilterExpression(string filter)
{
    return user => user.FirstName.Contains(filter) ||
            user.LastName.Contains(filter) ||
            (user.FirstName + "  " + user.LastName).Contains(filter);
}
```

Then pass that method to `Where`:

```c#
entities = entities.Where(GetFilterExpression(text));
```

I don't think you'll be able to use to extension method.

Comment: but that return is also a bool not an expression I think

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think you can use the extension method.

Comment: yeah, the extension method can't be used ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `String.Contains`, try using the EF function `Like`. You would change your `Contains` query to something like the following:

```
public static bool Contains(this User user, string filter)
{
    return EF.Functions.Like(filter, $"%{user.FirstName}%") ||
        EF.Functions.Like(filter, $"%{user.LastName}%") ||
        EF.Functions.Like(filter, $"%{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}%");
}
```

Though, if you don't need to search both starts with and ends with, it would be better to not use a full text search, but to limit on just starts with.

Comment: I had the same problem: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'where (False OrElse [entity].Contains(__filterText_1))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.'